# Actionscript 3.0 method keeps repeating, cant figure out why

Tags: actionscript-3, methods, actionscript

I'm having difficulty debugging my audio slider. I'm pretty sure my problems lies in the fact that one of my methods, `changeVolumeRedFireball` is just constantly repeating at a very fast rate. I get a glitchy sound every once in a while in my game, so it seems to correlate. I traced "output" inside the method and quickly found out it's repeating at a high rate.

Problem is, I cannot figure out WHERE this is coming from! One other note. This only starts repeating once I hold down my slider, hence activating the `changeVolumeRedFireball` from `dragSliderRedFireball`

I do have other methods from other classes referencing methods in this class. They only access `playSoundRedFireball` and `stopSoundRedFireball` though, so I don't see why that would have any effect. Also, this class is instantiated by my document class upon start up of the game. I suppose I'll put in the relevant code from the document class if requested, but I just didn't think it would affect this problem at all.

```
package {

        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.display.Graphics;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.media.Sound;
        import flash.media.SoundChannel;
        import flash.media.SoundTransform;
        import flash.geom.Rectangle;

        public class VolumeRedFireball extends Sprite {

                public var redFireballSnd:Sound = new Sound();
                public var redFireballChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
                //URLRequest=new URLRequest("solitude.wav");
                //Make sure you pass URLRequest an audio file on your computer.
                public var reqRedFireball:EnemyAppearSound = new EnemyAppearSound();
                public var boundaryRedFireball:Rectangle;
                public var spriteRedFireball:Sprite;
                public var sliderRedFireball:Sprite;
                public var xPosRedFireball:Number;
                public var yPosRedFireball:Number;
                public static var volRedFireball:Number = 1;

                public function VolumeRedFireball() {
                        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStageRedFireball,false,0,true);
                        volRedFireball=1;
                        redFireballChannel.soundTransform=new SoundTransform(volRedFireball)
                }

                public function onStageRedFireball(e:Event):void
                {
                    //We remove it immediately so that it doesn't get called multiple times
                    //As the instance is added to the display list tree
                    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStageRedFireball);

                    xPosRedFireball = 320;
                    yPosRedFireball = 170;

                    initRedFireball();
                }


                public function initRedFireball():void {
                        spriteRedFireball = new Sprite();
                        redFireballChannel.stop();
                        spriteRedFireball.graphics.beginFill(0x999999);
                        spriteRedFireball.graphics.drawRect(xPosRedFireball,yPosRedFireball,100,5);
                        spriteRedFireball.graphics.endFill();
                        addChild(spriteRedFireball);
                        spriteRedFireball.x-=spriteRedFireball.width/2;
                        sliderRedFireball = new Sprite();
                        sliderRedFireball.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                        sliderRedFireball.graphics.drawCircle(xPosRedFireball+50,yPosRedFireball, 15);
                        sliderRedFireball.graphics.endFill();
                        addChild(sliderRedFireball);
                        sliderRedFireball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragsliderRedFireball);
                        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopsliderRedFireball);
                        boundaryRedFireball=new Rectangle(-100,0,100,0);
                }


                public function dragsliderRedFireball(event:MouseEvent):void {
                        sliderRedFireball.startDrag(false,boundaryRedFireball);
                        sliderRedFireball.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dragsliderRedFireball);
                        sliderRedFireball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, changeVolumeRedFireball);
                }


                public function stopsliderRedFireball(event:MouseEvent):void {
                        sliderRedFireball.stopDrag();
                        sliderRedFireball.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopsliderRedFireball);
                }



                public function changeVolumeRedFireball(event:Event):void {
                        volRedFireball=1+Math.round(sliderRedFireball.x)/100;
                        redFireballChannel.soundTransform=new SoundTransform(volRedFireball);
                        trace("output");   
                }


                public function playSoundRedFireball():void
                {
                    redFireballChannel = reqRedFireball.play();
                }

                public function stopSoundRedFireball():void
                {
                    redFireballChannel.stop();
                }

        }

}
```

Comment: sliderRedFireball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, changeVolumeRedFireball); <== dernière ligne de dragsliderRedFireball. la méthode changeVolumeRedFireball est appellée à chaque frame (soit plusieurs dizaines de fois par seconde).

Comment: Let's see if google translate helps me here....

Comment: Ok so adding to changeVolumeRedFireball--->sliderRedFireball.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, changeVolumeRedFireball) should fix it?

Comment: Ha sorry. I forgot to speak in english. my bad. Vesper's answer seems to be what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing a `SoundTransform` during every frame isn't good, as you are essentially undermining the audio channel. It's better if you use `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE` to trigger volume change, as if mouse is moved, and volume slider is being dragged, then the SWF user apparently wants the volume to change. But if a user starts dragging the slider but does not move it, why changing the volume?

```
public function dragsliderRedFireball(event:MouseEvent):void {
                    sliderRedFireball.startDrag(false,boundaryRedFireball);
                    sliderRedFireball.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragsliderRedFireball);
                    sliderRedFireball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, changeVolumeRedFireball);
                    sliderRedFireball.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopsliderRedFireball);
            }


            public function stopsliderRedFireball(event:MouseEvent):void {
                    sliderRedFireball.stopDrag();
                    sliderRedFireball.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopsliderRedFireball);
                    sliderRedFireball.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, changeVolumeRedFireball);
                    sliderRedFireball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragsliderRedFireball);
            }
```

Also, you have messed up your listeners. First, you are not removing the enterframe listener after you stop dragging the fireball. Second, you are not adding a start-drag listener back after the fireball has been released. And third, in your `initRedFireball` you are adding `stopsliderRedFireball` as listener to **stage**, for a really strange reason, but you are attempting to remove it from `sliderRedFireball`. Please pay precise attention on where your listeners go, what do they listen and where do you remove them and from which objects. Misuse of an enterframe listener can build up pretty quickly, and spoil you all the fun.

Comment: thanks =), unfortunately this has caused my music and sound to totally disappear though. Trying to figure out why =(

Comment: Trace coordinates in `changeVolumeRedFireball()`, perhaps you are using wrong ones to calculate volume percentage. It's all up to using correct data.

Comment: Just a capitalization mistake at some point, found it! haha sorry. Ahhh but now the slider works and changes the volume, yet the sound is still playing at max volume -.-

Comment: Do some traces, still. It's possible that your volume setting is always above 1, resulting in max volume. It's also possible that you are speaking about your **next** instances of redfireball, which have their own slider and their own base volume of 1.

Comment: Yeah I did some traces and the slider works fine, I'm getting an output of 0 when I slide it all the way down (although it takes a little too longer to register the move, resulting in not the best slider). I feel like I only declare one instance since the only time I call an instance is when the document class is instantiated....I don't know where these other guys are coming from urgh